# Remove index.php from url for ONLY CI subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I get how to remove `index.php` from CI urls overall. The following works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /crm/v2/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However, it interfers with other code on the live site. This new CI version i'm adding is in a subdir named `v2`. Thus the layout is something like:

```
-originalDir
  --v2
-otherDirs
-.htaccess
-etc...
```

So in essence urls come out something like:

```
// Original page
https://www.site.com/originalDir/somepage.htm
// And this exist too
https://www.site.com/originalDir/index.php

// My new stuff
https://www.site.com/originalDir/v2/index.php/controller/etc...
// Desired effect withOUT affecting the original sites index.php page
//     aka, the below is what i WANT but NOT getting!
https://www.site.com/originalDir/v2/controller/etc...
```

I can code in a lot of languages, but never a lot of experience with these htaccess rewrites. Any ideas on how to make it rewrite index.php for ONLY the codeigniter sub-directory? I've tried a few things that seem to work locally, but not on the live server. Not sure the exact structure of rewrite code.

Comment: Your htaccess actually looks right, have you removed the index.php from the config.php file?

Comment: it is right, as i stated before, however there is old code on that same site that stops working. Thus i need an alternate solution.

Comment: Yeah, but what I meant is it really doesn't look like it should be affecting anything above that level. I'm not great with htaccess either though so...

Comment: @RickCalder NP, and thanks for the inquiry. I found my answer below. Putting the alternate solution in the v2 directory seems to be doing exactly as I intended and not affecting the rest of the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you want to only rewrite rules in the CI directory, and not point any URLs outside of that directory to it...**

Change your `RewriteRule` to match only URI's that start with your CI directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^crm/v2/(.*)$ /crm/v2/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Alternatively, you can put an .htaccess file in your `/crm/v2` directory, and specify a `RewriteBase`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /crm/v2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your alternate solution was exactly what I needed. So far, it seems to be working just fine with 0 interference! Will post back if I notice any problems. Until then, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using RewriteBase?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crm/v2
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have not tested this specifically with your information but this is from a template that I use for some of my projects.

Here is the documentation for RewriteBase: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

I hope this helps!

Comment: Given you a +1 for the documentation lead, though in the end, the alternate answer provided by @Cryode has worked perfect! Thanks for all the help!